# Can't connect to Azure ML Web Service in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

I deployed an automated ML in Azure Machine Learning Studio and I have my endpoint url (that is a http, not a https ?) and my primary key.

I got in Azure Data Factory, try to create a Azure ML Studio linked services to use the Azure Batch Execution, I put my http endpoint in https and my primary key but every time i try, if i put http, it's 404 error and if i put https, i got a timeout.

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Based on the link:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/getting-started-with-azure-data-factory-and-azure-machine-learning-4/, it should be https, not http. Would you please try to provide more details of your error message?

Comment: My only error message is a timeout message, nothing more unfortunately :/